# Simple XML framework - convert inherited classes with a single Converter

Tags: java, xml-serialization, simple-framework

I am using SimpleXML framework. What I have three classes, B and C extends A:

*Classes*:

```
public class A {
}
public class B extends A {
}
public class C extends A {
}
```

I can register a Converter for the class A:

*Seriailization*:

```
Registry registry = new Registry();
registry.bind(A.class, AConverter.class);
Strategy strategy = new RegistryStrategy(registry);
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
```

*Converter*:

```
public class AConverter implements Converter<A> {
@Override
public A read(InputNode n) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
public void write(OutputNode n, A p) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

**Problem**: AConverter is used for class A only (not for classes B and C).

**How it is possible to register the AConverter to all the instances of class A (i.e. B and C) ?**

*NOTE: I think combination of (Matcher & Transform) is not good for my case because I will need many inner blocks inside of the   ...   in future.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
registry.bind(A.class, AConverter.class);
registry.bind(B.class, AConverter.class);
registry.bind(C.class, AConverter.class);
```

Comment: Yes, it would work but the problem is there will be hundreds of A subclasses (also in third party libraries) and to register each would be quite tricky.